# running a macro across all opened Excel files

Tags: excel, vba

New to VBA code and struggling to figure out why my code isn't working.
I want to run a macro across all open Excel files.
The macro that works on one file at a time is:

````
```
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim R As Range, cellsToDel As String
'looking for cells that contain the word '1. Staff Home'
Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues)
'if found
Do While Not R Is Nothing
'get cells address to be deleted
cellsToDel = "A1" & ":K" & R.Row - 1
'delete the cells
ActiveSheet.Range(cellsToDel).Delete xlShiftUp
'looking for cells that contain the word '1. Staff Home' again
Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A:K").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues)
Loop
End Sub

Sub Unwrap_Text()
'unwrap text in all cells'
ActiveSheet.Range("A:K").WrapText = False
End Sub
````

but when I try to wrap it in a macro to run on all open workbooks it doesn't work:

````
```
Sub DoAll()
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
Dim R As Range, cellsToDel As String
'looking for cells that contain the word '1. Staff Home'
Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues)
'if found
Do While Not R Is Nothing
'get cells address to be deleted
cellsToDel = "A1" & ":K" & R.Row - 1
'delete the cells
ActiveSheet.Range(cellsToDel).Delete xlShiftUp
'looking for cells that contain the word '1. Staff Home' again
Set R = ActiveSheet.Range("A:K").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues)
Loop
Next wb
End Sub
```
````

I've seen examples of macros that can run on Excel files in a directory, however the files in my directory are .html files that I've opened in Excel and want to remove a bunch of rows of navigation links that are irrelevant for my needs.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for replying, isn't that what the For Each is doing?

Comment: Do your  Excel files only have a single tab?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes

Comment: IMHO, it's dangerous to write code that runs on all open Excel files. What if you have more files open than you think?

Comment: this shouldn't be a problem @teylyn as I will manually open the html files in Excel, so I'll know what is open.

Comment: @BigBen how do I add another loop to this?

Comment: Trying changing the `ActiveSheet` instances to `wb.Worksheets(1)`. I don't think you need another loop.

Answer (score 1):

If there's only one sheet:

```vb
Sub DoAll()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range, cellsToDel As String
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        Set R = ws.Range("A:A").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues)
        Do While Not R Is Nothing
            ws.Range("A1:K" & (R.Row - 1)).Delete xlShiftUp
            Set R = ws.Range("A:K").Find("1. Staff Home", LookIn:=xlValues) 'A:A ?
        Loop
    Next wb
    
End Sub
```

Note your two posted `Find()` lines are looking at different ranges.  Is that intentional?

Comment: thanks Tim, but this is returning a 438 error. yes, that Set R should have been ws.Range("A:A")

Comment: Error is on which line?

Comment: Sorry, it's not returning a line number. It just says: Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: My typo - had `wb.Range` in stead of `ws.Range`